# Airflow - get value at specific index of the task output

Tags: python, airflow

I have a PythonOperator task in Airflow that outputs e.g. `['instance-id', 128.2.4.33]` and in the downstream task I reference this task' output using dynamic task mapping by `expand` and I reference the output like `upstream_python_task.output`, however this gives me the entire list with both values but my downstream task (`EC2StartInstanceOperator`) needs only 1 value (`instance_id`). I tried `upstream_python_task.output[0]` but that gives an error. How to reference the first element of the output?

Code:

```py
def get_files():
    return [['23', 'abcd'], ['49', 'xyz']]

def create_instance(index, some_param, **kwargs):
    return ['<instance-id>', '<ip-address>']

...
with dag:
    run_get_files = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'get-files',
        python_callable = get_files,
    )

    run_create_ec2_instance = PythonOperator.partial(
            task_id = 'create-instance',
            python_callable = create_instance,
        ).expand(
            op_args = run_get_files.output
    )

    start_instance = EC2StartInstanceOperator.partial(
        task_id = 'start-instance',
        region_name = 'eu-central-1',
    ).expand(
        instance_id = run_get_files.output[0], # error
    )
```

Comment: are you expending the `EC2StartInstanceOperator`using this list? can you provide your code?

Comment: @HusseinAwala yes, code added